# IWebBrowser2::Navigate2 error handling

Tags: c++, com, error-handling, iwebbrowser2

What is the correct way to handle errors? I've code like following, handling all error codes I've found on MSDN and still, sometimes, I've received error "Unknown".

```
HRESULT hr = pwb->Navigate2(&URL, &Flag, &TargetFrameName, &PostData, &Headers);
if(FAILED(hr))
{
    std::string message("Navigate2 failed with reason: ");
    switch(hr)
    {
        // The operation was successful.
        case S_OK:
            message.append("S_OK");
            break;
        // One or more parameters are invalid.
        case E_INVALIDARG:
            message.append("E_INVALIDARG");
            break;
        // Out of memory.
        case E_OUTOFMEMORY:
            message.append("E_OUTOFMEMORY");
            break;
        // The operation failed.
        case E_FAIL:
            message.append("E_FAIL");
            break;
        case E_ACCESSDENIED:
            message.append("E_ACCESSDENIED");
            break;
        case E_POINTER:
            message.append("E_POINTER");
            break;
        case E_UNEXPECTED:
            message.append("E_UNEXPECTED");
            break;
        default:
            message.append("Unknown");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a few variations on how to handle COM errors. Strategies include use of cascading `if SUCCEEDED()` or centralized function error handling using `goto on FAILED()` among others. There's some good information on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485842%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

As to interpreting error codes, `FormatMessage()` will often make your work easier - here's an example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687061%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (included below for clarity)

[Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687061(v=vs.85).aspx]

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <tchar.h>

    void ErrorDescription(HRESULT hr) 
    { 
         if(FACILITY_WINDOWS == HRESULT_FACILITY(hr)) 
             hr = HRESULT_CODE(hr); 
         TCHAR* szErrMsg; 

         if(FormatMessage( 
           FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER|FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, 
           NULL, hr, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), 
           (LPTSTR)&szErrMsg, 0, NULL) != 0) 
         { 
             _tprintf(TEXT("%s"), szErrMsg); 
             LocalFree(szErrMsg); 
         } else 
             _tprintf( TEXT("[Could not find a description for error # %#x.]\n"), hr); 
    }
```

In the call above, the flags indicate that windows will allocate memory for error messages (which you have to free - use `LocalFree()`) and that it will look for error messages in the system message tables (`FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM`). Sometimes, (or often depending on the kind of libraries you use) - no corresponding error descriptions will be found in the system message tables.

In cases like these you may either handle the error description yourself (as you have done in your example) or attempt to load a library's message tables directly. To do this, use the `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE` and supply a module handle as the `lpSource` parameter to the `FormatMessage()` function.

Here's an example:

```
std::wstring StackExample::getLastError( HRESULT hr ) 
{
    LPWSTR lpMsgBuf;
    DWORD ret;
    std::wstring def(L"(UNKNOWN)");
    ret = FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE,
        GetModuleHandle(TEXT("imapi2.dll")),
        hr,
        0,
        (LPWSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );

    if(ret)
    {
        std::wstring last(lpMsgBuf);
        LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
        return last;
    }
    return def;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's looks like solution I've looked for. Btw I've also found the reason of error in my case, maybe it wolud be useful for someone: looks like Navigate2 fails if IWebbrowser is in "busy" state(and sometimes is busy for reaaaaaly long)

Answer (score 0):

`HRESULT` error codes are actually `LONG` type with blocks of bits having individual meaning. That is, it is unrealistic to handle every error in `switch` statement.

If you have specific handling for specific error code, you do it. Otherwise you normally check the returned for success/failure using [`SUCCEEDED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and `FAILED` macros:

```
if(FAILED(nResult))
{
  // TODO: Handle the failed operation here
}
```

See also: [Error Codes in COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485841%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> To check whether a COM method succeeds, examine the high-order bit of
>   the returned HRESULT. The Windows SDK headers provide two macros that
>   make this easier: the SUCCEEDED macro and the FAILED macro. The
>   SUCCEEDED macro returns TRUE if an HRESULT is a success code and FALSE
>   if it is an error code.